# ¿Cómo ejecutar Streamlit VSC?

Tags: python-3.7

NO puedo ejecutar streamlit desde mi código, siempre me genera el siguiente mensaje :

2024-01-21 21:54:16.996
Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following
command:

```
streamlit run f:/Crear una app con streamlit/uber_pickups.py [ARGUMENTS]
```

PS F:\Crear una app con streamlit>

El código en básico :
mport streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

st.title('Uber pickups in NYC')